# Determine if a string of characters is 9 characters long and all numeric

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

My regex skills are a bit rusty.  Can someone provide a expression that I can use in javascript to match on a 9 digit string with all numberic values?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to find that number inside a larger string?  (if yes, then phihags and Stefan's answers are wrong.)  Also, are 10-digit numbers ok?  (if no, then Jon's answer is wrong).

Comment: Phihag's and Stefan's answers are correct for what I need, but I'm finding that although it works fine in JavaScript (my original question), the same syntax doesn't appear to work in .NET.  Ugh!

Comment: try removing the `/` at the begining and end.  So the C# regex would be `@"^\d{9}$"`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
/^[0-9]{9}$/
```

Answer (score 5):

If that's the only restriction:

```
/^\d{9}$/
```

Answer (score 4):

The regex is simple and short:

```
/^\d{9}$/
```

(unfortunately, SO does not let the answer be as well)

Comment: Depending how this is used... `"a012345678d".test(/\d{9}/)` -> a truthy value, `/\d{9}/.test("a012345678d")` -> true. `/\d{9}/.exec("a012345678d")` -> a truth value. Anyway, point is, none of the above functions *anchor* implicitly.

Comment: @pst: Speed mistake, sorry. Fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to find a 9-digit number inside a larger string, and >9 digit numbers are not ok, you can use this regex:

```
(?:^|\D)(\d{9})(?:\D|$)
```

Then, take the first group.

Edit: got the grouping right.

Comment: +1, but even better use `(^|\D)` at the beginning of your regex. Like this a match can occur at the string start as well, as a sole `\D` needs to consume a character...